# Eager fetched associations does not show up in response

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-rest

I'm writing an extension to SDR, which will allow users to extend requested entities with associations. Everything works until Resource leaves `RepositoryRestController`. Then associated data is lost somewhere.
The same situations appears when I set association to be fetched eagerly. Is there any code responsible for removing associated data from response?

Answer (score 0):

The code responsible removing associated data from response is in class `AssociationOmittingSerializerModifier`